# .NET MVC2 Equivalent of 'rake routes'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Is there a .NET MVC2 Equivalent to Ruby on Rails' `rake routes` command? I'm having some weird routing issues and something like that would be infinitely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see what your routes are doing, you can use Phil Haack's [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)  and [Route Tester for unit testing](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/05/routeevaluator-for-unit-testing-routes.aspx) your routes.